# Is javascript / HTML5 capable of supporting "flash like" animation and drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, flash, html

With apple browsers not supporting flash or silverlight, there is a real incentive to avoid flash / silverlight to avoid losing that audience when building a web site.  That being said there is certain functionality that it seems like you can only really do in flash / silverlight

for example [alot of simple games where you can move things on the screen like this site](http://www.dailyfreegames.com/flash/dress-up-games/princess.html) all seem to be built in flash. also, [a lot of drag and drop functionality where you can drag one object onto another like these game site](http://www.sweetdressupgames.com/play/sunny-look-dress-up)s.
  After lots of searching I can't find any that are not either flash or silverlight based.

In particular i am looking for drag and drop support of one element onto another

my question is if you need this type of functionality is javascript / html 5 able to do this type of stuff (so you can support iphone / ipad) or are you out of luck.

is there any resource that highlight examples or suggestions of trying to do this type of interactive functionality and how / if you can do this type of stuff without silverlight / flash.  also, if anyone has any good examples of existing site who are doing that today that would be great as well.

Comment: Check the [rapheal](http://raphaeljs.com/) demos.

Comment: Also worth looking into: http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/demos/

Comment: Try visiting http://www.chromeexperiments.com/, I hope you will rephrase your question

Comment: Besides Safari in iOS, exactly which Apple browser(s) do not support Flash or Silverlight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to be a long discussion about the ability of html5 to compete with flash.

In my opinion jquery is not any close to performance flash or silverlight animation give.

if the comparison is in terms of drag-and-drop, menu dropdowns, fadeIn.fadeOut - jQuery is competitive.

If i will see the jQuery cartoons with lot of layers and objects moving simultaneously - i will probably agree that jQuery has competitive performance.

the things are compare to see the difference:

1. magnifying glass over the raster picture
2. smoke/water/fire emulation
3. compound 3D objects like fractals with deep branches

when HTML5 will have it - then i will agree that it has competitive performance. All that i see today is picture slideshows and couple of games that work on html5.

Comment: I agree that HTML and JavaScript alone cannot be used to make the kind of games we are used to playing in Flash, but if all you want is a drag and drop UI then it works fine. One issue with the iPhone and jQuery UI - the draggable event doesn't work. The equivalent for touchscreen devices is http://www.jqtouch.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Easel.js](http://easeljs.com/) by Grant Skinner, used in [Pirates Love Daisies](http://www.pirateslovedaisies.com/).

Also, other frameworks are:

- [enchant](https://github.com/wise9/enchant.js)
- [limeJS](http://www.limejs.com/)
- [akihabara](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery UI has that for long time, works in all modern browsers, not just HTML5

[JQuery UI Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: i haven't seen any jquery ui demos or site that compete on these topics . . do you have any examples ?

Comment: the link i included demonstrates a drag and drop event. You can drag and drop the gray rectangle onto the orange one. It may not look very fancy but those pages are more for documentation purposes. Here is another one: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/ and another one: http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag_drop_tree.html

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout [canvasdemos.com](http://www.canvasdemos.com/type/games/). It has a lot of good examples of what can be done. You can take a look at the source code behind these - some even help you in that regard. e.g. the [pool game](http://dave.whipp.name/snooker/canvas_pool.html)

Other good examples include the [doom like "game"](http://www.benjoffe.com/code/demos/canvascape/textures) (you can walk around in 3D dungeons).

The [Frog Log](http://mix10k.visitmix.com/Entry/Details/169) game was the winner in the [10KB coding challange](http://mix10k.visitmix.com/)

Also [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/48-excellent-html5-demos/) was the first result for a search of *html5 animation demo* in google. It has links to 48 demos. Some of them are really cool. Unfortunately the code for a lot of these have been minified, but they still might give you a few ideas about what you can achieve.

So it's fine for making simple dressup type games. However, if you are looking to make anything that's CPU intensive, you should look into some performance benchmarks like [this](http://blog.hjaelpmignu.dk/2011/03/html5-canvas-with-javascript-and-flash-player-performance/). HTML5/Canvas based animation is still quite far behind flash in terms of performance. Getting consistent behaviour across the various browsers will also be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 and related technologies (WebSockets, WebGL, web storage, File API, media capture, etc) are quickly moving towards parity with (and in some cases exceeding) what can be done in Flash/Silverlight.

The [HTML5 Rocks slides](http://slides.html5rocks.com) are a reasonable starting point to see what is possible (you need an HTML5 capable browser). In particular, the [Canvas example](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#canvas-2d-example) demonstrates image manipulation (drag, rotate, resize) which is the core functionality needed to implement dress-up games.

Answer (score 1):

Flash was designed for animation. The tweens were meant to be used for animating drawings. Because it was marketed to every Tom, Dick and Harry, people started using it to animate hideous menus and flying content text. And Adobe complied to this new use, building an abode of total chaos.

Flash is still the best animation engine for the web, it should never have catered to full flash websites.

Many HTML5 fans out there, but it needs to be said: Canvas is a decade behind Flash. But for everything other than animation, Flash is an abomination.

Comment: To design animations from a designer/animator's prospective flash is a superior tool. To create programmative animations canvas and svg are not that far behind with some abstraction libraries.

Comment: Good point! I did not consider the difference between programmatic animations and mousy(?) animation. Canvas is behind in programmatic animations, but I think it will catch up much faster than Adobe can advance. Though I still maintain that the performance gap will take a very long time to close.

Comment: You actually think there is a performance gap? I've only noticed a performance difference for very intensive animations. The only difference is that both flash & canvas run at 5 fps but flash makes the frame by frame transition look a lot smoother. of course were not comparing IE8 canvas emulation to flash here, that's unfair.

Comment: http://flash4ipad.com/canvas-flash-10-1-animation-performance-compared/, http://www.eleqtriq.com/2010/02/canvas-svg-flash/, http://pacoup.com/2011/02/03/flash-vs-html5-performance/, http://www.yopsolo.fr/wp/2010/11/16/flash-vs-html5-performance-test/

Comment: out of the demos I could visually compare / run myself. I found that flash was 20% faster on most and about 80% slower on a few. From my own real world differences I find that flash / html5 is only as fast as the developer is competent. Both are usable technologies.

Answer (score 1):

In old browsers, you can emulate drag'n'drop of elemnts **from the DOM** but in new browsers, you can also drag'n'drop files (like images) and there are events for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop

For flash-like animations, it's been possible with JavaScript for a long time but doing some bug ones was really hard and often slowing down the page.
Now, there is canvas and WebGL that allow you to do it in a more convinient way (for the complex ones).
And with canvas, WebGL, CSS animations (if you use the tric to make the browser think it's 3D), you get CPU accelerated so it's way faster.
There is also requestAnimationFrame that allows to optimise the reflows and therefore the script.

The best example I know on what can be done is the Quake II port to the Web :

- Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhMN0wlITLk&feature=player_embedded
- Project's site: http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/

Answer (score 0):

as said in soe of the answers above, I'm pretty sure j[query's draggable/droppable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#default) will do the job for you if you just need a basic drag and drop dress me up type of game. Basic premise is this:

1. in the default example, your avatar to wear the clothes would be a div with a png/gif.jpg background image of a girl/boy whatever(instead of an orange drop here background)
2. the clothes will be the "drag me to my target" objects in the example. you can create them as divs or even image tags that have the draggable class in them so you can drag them around and drop them in the orange boxes/avatars.
3. you can save the data using ajax, which is also covered in the examples there(or other tutorials in the net, it's easy)
4. ???
5. PROFIT

Just try it out and see for yourself. If you need any help you can just ask here again, but I do think that the jquery UI answers are valid answers to your problem.

I don't have an example site to show you, but I'm pretty sure given some images and stuff I can whip out something...if I had the time lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do these "flash-like" things now in HTML5 web browsers. Check out the examples at http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

Answer (score 0):

In fact HTML5/CSS3/JS can do anything flash can do. But there are some drawback :

- It is not yet mature. Lot of bugs, lot of difference in implementation depending of browsers and many people simply don't have yet browsers that support it.
- Adobe has a really nice set of tools that help making complex flash applications. This doesn't exist (yet ?) at the same level for HTML5.

On a side note, neither flash, neither HTML5 will really shine on mobiles phone. People prefer native applications anyway. You might need to provide a web version, but you'll need too a app version (one per big phone player).

We can speculate how HTML5 will rule the word in the next few years, but as of now, impact are limited outside of nice looking demo that consume 100% of CPU (really, really bad for mobile device).

For drag and drop support, anybody can do that - in HTML4 and in any browser with a few lines of javascript - inside one page, or can think to do it on between 2 browser windows of the same website. Doing drag & drop between browser and any native desktop application is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

For a great example of what you can do with HTML5 in terms of drag and drop, I suggest you take a look at this [article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/02/an-html5-offline-image-editor-and-uploader-application/) and in particular the short demo at the beginning. The article also highlights a few other goodies that come with HTML5, such as localStorage and the HTML5 Canvas.

For a more detailed tutorial on the HTML5 drag-n-drop API specifically (really it is a Javascript API), take a look at this [other article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/file-drag-and-drop-in-firefox-3-6/). It is dated from December 2009 but still valid.

Lastly, this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFmuNApHFec) gives you a good insight on some of the cool visual effects that you'll be able to do with HTML5 (SVG, Canvas, CSS3, WebGL, ...). More of a marketing video I'll admit but a good illustration of some of the more powerful HTML5 features (at least from a visual stand point) and of what we'll start seeing in our browsers in a not so distant future...

**Disclaimer:** I don't work for Mozilla. I just happen to have researched this topic in the past and found that the material produced by Mozilla, and in particular the demos from Paul Rouget, to be the most instructive.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery UI is an amazing library...

Drag: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default

Drop: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

I belive that the droppable examples will answer your question of "*In particular i am looking for drag and drop support of one element onto another*"